# In MIPS, why can't we use a word stored in the FPU as the base address for lwc1 / swc1?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

For example, this is permitted:

```
.data
   try: .word 15
.text
   la $s0, try
   mtc1 $s0, $f1
   lwc1 $f2, ($s0)
```

This is not:

```
.data
   try: .word 15
.text
   la $s0, try
   mtc1 $s0, $f1
   lwc1 $f2, ($f1)
```

Even though the registers contain the same bit pattern? I have checked [documentation](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2008fa/MIPS_Vol2.pdf#page=139) about the instructions to clarify, but the only thing I notice is that 'Coprocessor Unusable' is a possible exception...but **why**?

Comment: MIPS instructions are fixed-size. There are 5 bits in the instruction used for encoding which register to use as the base address. Those 5 bits can encode 32 different values, and those 32 values had already been picked to represent the 32 general-purpose registers.

Comment: *Even though the registers contain the same bit pattern?* - exactly.  It would take an *extra* bit somewhere to encode whether you want an integer or FP register to be used as the base address, and a lot of wiring and muxers to select a value from the FP vs. integer register file to feed to the address-calculation hardware.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that the instruction encodings don't allow for that.  The `lwc1` instruction is an I-Type instruction, which allows 2 bits to designate which coprocessor, 5 bits for `base` register and 5 bits for the `rt` coprocessor target register.  Like other loads & stores there is a 16-bit immediate.  The 16-bit signed offset is added to the contents of GPR base to form the effective address.

A longer answer is that the designers choose that the purpose of the floating point registers is to store floating point values rather than pointers.  As part of this they chose to focus the floating point unit on floating point calculations alone.  Floating point operations focus on complex numeric calculations and also involve rounding hidden bits — these operations are not appropriate for pointers.

They left load and store operations to the main processor, instead of adding load & store units to the coprocessor.  `lwc1` is executed in the main processor, as an ordinary I-type instruction.

They also left pointer arithmetic, which is base address computation, and integer shifts and adds, to the main processor, instead of adding that to the floating point unit, where that would be duplicative.

Could they have added instructions to dereference a floating point value?  Yes, I suppose so, assuming they had sufficient encoding space left.  (Being a fixed-size instructions set encoding space is more at a premium than a variable length instruction set like x86.  Let's note that RISC V has a variable length instruction set (in increments of 2 bytes).)

It would have made more sense to add to the general purpose integer registers if they wanted more pointers in registers, rather than to use the floating point coprocessor, but MIPS is already generally considered register rich with two dozen or more integer registers available for user computation such as for pointers.